How does this MOSFET-based Schmitt trigger work?
This circuit is an inverting NMOS Schmitt trigger. I'm having trouble understanding how exactly it achieves hysteresis.
If Q3 is removed, this circuit becomes a NMOS NAND gate with both inputs tied together, basically an inverter. So Q3 must be the key component in this circuit.
What exactly does Q3 do and how does this circuit work?


Have you tried simulating it? There is a built-in schematic entry and simulation tool right here in the editor.

I simulated it in Falstad. The circuit converted a sine wave to a square wave so it works but that didn’t help me understand it.

So you looked at just V(In) and V(Out)? What about the other node in the circuit? Or branch currents?

What will turning on Q3 do to the Vgs of Q2?

By removing Q3, and focussing only on Q1 and Q2, you find that you're left with an inverter, providing a high output when the input is low, and vice versa:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Both transistors must be simultaneously switched on for the output to be low, but if either transistor is off then the output will be high, pulled up to +5V by R1.
The state of a MOSFET is determined by the potential difference between gate and source, \$V_{GS}=V_G - V_S\$. Q1, the lower transistor, will be on if \$V_{IN} > V_{GS(TH)}\$, since its source potential is always 0V. The upper transistor Q2 though will only turn on if \$V_{IN} > V_S + V_{GS(TH)}\$, since its source is not necessarily grounded. This gives us some flexibility to alter the threshold at which Q2 switches on, by controlling potential \$V_S\$ at its source, node S.
Obviously If Q1 is on, \$V_S=0V\$, since Q1 short-circuits S to ground, but when Q1 and Q2 are both off, node S is essentially floating, and its potential can be set to whatever value we want. If during the off state we somehow raise \$V_S\$, we are raising the threshold at which Q2 can switch on again.
In other words, we can assert different switching thresholds for each state \$V_{OUT}\$ high and \$V_{OUT}\$ low, which is the core principle behind hysteresis in a schmitt trigger. This is the role of Q3, to set \$V_S\$ to different potentials in each state.
Q3 is switched on when the output is high (Q1 and Q2 off), which raises \$V_S\$, thereby raising the input threshold at which Q2 begins to switch on. When \$V_{IN}\$ rises past that threshold of \$V_S+V_{GS(TH)}\$, Q2 switches on (Q1 will already be on, since its own threshold is lower), and \$V_{OUT}\$ falls. Q3 then switches off, and the new switching threshold becomes just \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ again.
It's important to note that Q3 is configured as a source-follower (AKA common-drain), meaning that its source is always about \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ lower than its gate. In that configuration, with gate connected to OUT, you can expect source potential \$V_S = +5V - V_{GS(TH)}\$ when \$V_{OUT}=+5V\$.
Putting Q3 back into the circuit, the two distinct potentials \$V_S\$ corresponding to \$V_{OUT}=0V\$ and \$V_{OUT}=+5V\$ can be measured:

simulate this circuit
As I mentioned above, node S is floating when Q1 and Q2 are off. In that state \$V_S\$ is ambiguous, so I've added R2 to give the source-follower a load to sink some current, so that my assertion that \$V_S=+5V-V_{GS(TH)}\$ is correct. The circuit's switching thresholds without R2 are somewhat vague, and I recommend that you do the same.
\$V_S\$ is shown in orange below, as \$V_{IN}\$ oscillates between high and low:

Since I've set \$V_{GS(TH)}=3V\$ for Q3, and given that Q3 is a source follower, it's no surprise that \$V_S\$ goes between \$+5V-3V=+2V\$ and 0V. This 2V offset to the switching threshold for Q2 will mean that we should expect to see hysteresis if we apply a continuously changing \$V_{IN}\$:

simulate this circuit

The amount of hysteresis (the gap between switching thresholds, shown by the green markers) is also dependent on the individual \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ of Q1 and Q2, so while you might expect hysteresis to be 2V, this isn't the case.
Beware the potential for large shoot-through current during switching. The transitions of Q1 and Q3 between on and off is not instantaneous, meaning that there is a short interval during which both are partially conductive, providing a direct route for current from +5V to ground:


But where has the omnipresent positive feedback gone?

@Circuitfantasist it's still there, as OUT rises, S rises, Q2 switches more off, OUT rises even more, and vice versa

Wouldn't it be good to see a common-drain and common-gate stage connected in a loop, and thus make the connection with Mr. Otto Schmitt's creation?

You have a couple good answers as to how it functions, and with low-current MOSFETs it might be suitable for some purposes, however let me illustrate why it's a pretty crummy circuit with 2N7000s (as in, it will fail if you have the wrong sustained input) and disastrously bad if you use a more beefy MOSFET such as the SOT23 AO3416
Here I've simulated it by applying a ramp with a small (100mV peak) sine wave so you can see that the ST functionality is there. But look at the dissipation of M1 (cyan) and M3 (magenta) traces in the top pane. Peaking at about 200W!

And here is an example of the original circuit self-destructing under unusual but possible conditions, with \$\pi\$ volts applied:

M3 is dissipating a typical power of 538mW, well above absolute maximum for a TO92 even at 25°C. This dissipation is sustained since I'm perversely holding the input voltage just below the switching point.
That said, this circuit (or, more accurately, a complementary and augmented version of it) is used in CMOS ST ICs, however the transistors are much smaller so the peak currents are tolerable (note the additional complementary P1/P2/P3 and the added element P5/N5- the latter explained in the app note I linked above), on top of the cascaded inverters at the output (in the case of the MM74C14 and 5V supply, the peak current is less than 0.2mA) :

What is not communicated in the above schematic is that there are several different 'strengths' of p & n-channel MOSFETs in the one circuit.

Thanks for pointing out that this circuit is suboptimal in terms of power dissipation. Although, could this problem be solved by placing a 1k resistor between 5V and the drain of Q3?

@nmos_cpu Why don't you simulate that and the effect on the hysteresis?

Adding the resistor removed all hysteresis. However, adding another 1k resistor between GND and source of Q1 restored the hysteresis, so this might work as a potential solution.

Looking for familiar circuit

This circuit is an inverting NMOS Schmitt trigger.

I have to admit, it took me a long time to figure out that this odd-looking diagram was actually showing the famous Otto Schmitt circuit. Once I turned Q3 by 90 degrees counterclockwise, everything made sense.

What exactly does Q3 do and how does this circuit work?

As you probably know, the classic Schmitt trigger consists of two source-coupled transistors (Q1 and Q2 in Schematic 1 below) with a common resistor Rs. They can be considered as a common-gate (Q1) and common-drain (Q2) stage connected in a positive feedback loop. From another viewpoint, Rd1, Rd2 and Rs form a voltage divider with switchable ratio.
So, Q3 in your schematic is one of the two transistors required to assemble a Schmitt trigger.
Classic Schmitt trigger
Let's first recall how the classic 2-transistor Schmitt trigger works by examining it using CircuitLab. This will help us explain the exotic 3-transistor circuit that is the subject of your question.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Initially, Vin = 0 so Q1 is off and Q2 is on. Rd2-Rs voltage divider sets the high threshold VH. When Vin approaches VH, Q1 begins turning on and Q2 off. The self-reinforcing positive feedback accelerates the transition. Finally, Q1 is on and Q2 off.

Now the voltage divider is formed by Rd1 and Rs. When Vin begins decreasing and approaches VL, Q1 begins turning off and Q2 on. The positive feedback accelerates the transition. Finally, Q1 is off and Q2 on and the voltage divider is formed by Rd2 and Rs as in the beginning.
Schmitt trigger with dynamic Rs
Now, let's replace the source resistor Rs with another MOSFET and try to understand the purpose of this.
A possible suggestion is that it acts as a "dynamic Rs resistor" that changes its resistance at the time of switching so as to assist it:

When Q2 tries to switch on, Q2 is on thus decreasing the threshold voltage Vs and helping Q2 in its desire to be on.

When Q2 tries to switch off, Q2 is off thus increasing Vs and helping Q2 to be off.



simulate this circuit

One benefit of this would be to speed up switching and another to replace a resistor with a transistor in microelectronics. Maybe with this purpose Rd2 is removed. We can only guess...

Made with microcap v12.
I tried to simulate this circuit to prepare explanations.
Here is the behavior of this circuit.
It seems that it can be explained in 9 parts (?) ...

I add a simulation without Q3 for seeing what happens.

